# Составьте массив словарей с 6 билетами

Tags: python

Я не понимаю, так ли надо было ее решать.. Подскажите пожалуйста. Вот задача:
Составьте массив словарей с 6 билетами на поезд.

Ключ в словаре — место пассажира в вагоне.

Затем выведите все билеты на экран.

```
base = {'Билет 1, Место 1':{'Дата': '22.11.2099','Пункт назначения': 'Россия, Москва'}}
base.update({'Билет 2, Место 2':{'Дата': '22.11.2099','Пункт назначения': 'Россия , Москва'}})
base.update({'Билет 3, Место 3':{'Дата': '22.11.2099','Пункт назначения': 'Россия , Москва'}})
base.update({'Билет 4, Место 4':{'Дата': '22.11.2099','Пункт назначения': 'Россия , Москва'}})
base.update({'Билет 5, Место 5':{'Дата': '22.11.2099','Пункт назначения': 'Россия , Москва'}})
base.update({'Билет 6, Место 6':{'Дата': '22.11.2099','Пункт назначения': 'Россия , Москва'}})
print (base.keys())
```

Answer (score 1):

если я правильно понял, то словарь описывает один билет

например так:

```
tickets = [
    {1: "Иванов Иван Иванович"},
    {2: "Петров Пётр Петрович"},
    {3: "Сидоров Сидр Сидорович"},
]

print(tickets)
```

вместо строки в словаре можно конечно что угодно добавлять, хоть другой словарь с данными как у вас и т.д.